# WPF ComboBox and SelectedItem Binding to XML DataSource

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a comboBox inside a DataTemplate as below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboImages" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=ImageName, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
   <ComboBoxItem>Image1.jpg</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>Image2.jpg</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>Image3.jpg</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to update the property (ImageName) of my XML datasource with the `SelectedItem` of the comboxBox.

Any clue what's wrong with the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I have managed to solve the problem but now I'm having another one.
I have three ComboBoxes showing the images from the same source file(xml). User picks image the image from each combobox  as selection 1, 2 3.
I'm binding those 3 selections to three different fields in the product datasource(xml file) as Logo1, Logo2, Logo3) but all three comboboexs are somehow gets binded together. If I pick up and image from selection 1, the other two combo boxes are getting updated with the selection 1.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving your ComboBox outside of the DataTemplate, and do your ComboBox customisation inside an ItemTemplate.

```
<Window x:Class="BindXML.Views.MainView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Main Window" Height="400" Width="800">

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="comboTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@ImageName}" Width="70" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="src" XPath="/Root">
        <x:XData>
            <Root xmlns="">
                <Item ImageName="Image1.jpg" />
                <Item ImageName="Image2.jpg" />
                <Item ImageName="Image3.jpg" />
            </Root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
  <DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboImages1"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource src}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource comboTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}"                      
                  SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=ImageName, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboImages2"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource src}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource comboTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}"                      
                  SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=ImageName, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  >
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The following test code-behind shows different ComboxBox selected items:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     XmlElement e1 = cboImages1.SelectedItem as XmlElement;
     if ( e1 != null )
     {
        XmlAttribute result1 = e1.Attributes["ImageName"] as XmlAttribute;
        if ( result1 != null )
        {
           string name1 = result1.Value;
        }
     }

     XmlElement e2 = cboImages2.SelectedItem as XmlElement;
     if ( e2 != null )
     {
        XmlAttribute result2 = e2.Attributes["ImageName"] as XmlAttribute;
        if (result2 != null)
        {
           string name2 = result2.Value;
        }
     }
  }
```